# Select distinct rows from different servers table

Tags: sql-server

I am facing an issue. The issue is as follows: 
I have an employee table in 2 servers where empid and username are different from server to server though the employee is same employee.

Table fields name (partials) 
empId(pk),username,password,FirstName,LastName,supervisorId,photo etc. There is no SSN field. supervisorid, photo could be null.

How can i retrieve distinct records where same employee in multiple servers?

Is there any way to distinguished whether it is same employee or not?

Any hints/idea will be more appreciable. I am totally stuck to find a solution.

Comment: I assume empid is unique for each employee. If so, that's how you distinguish between employees. If nit, you have to tell us what makes them unique.

Comment: What happens when you have two employees with the same name?

Comment: Thanks everyone. employeeid is primary key. employeeid and username are not the same on all servers. e.g. Server1: EmployeeTable: emp001 indicates morshed but Server2: EmployeeTable: emp001 indicates someone else not morshed. May be, in Server2 emp007 indicates morshed. There could be same name multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

`UNION` the tables together and use that query as a subquery of your `SELECT DISTINCT`.  Use the `username` or `FirstName` and `LastName` as your `HAVING COUNT` fields.

Comment: Thanks Tripp. i am not clear how it will work? I wrote a sql query but does not get desired result. Would you make it elaborate with an example or sample query?